# Show gutters for errors in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the `eslint` extension, and its producing errors in my code. However is there a way to show a error-indicating gutter on the lines with a error? Currently I just have this red underline:
[image]

Is there a way to show a high-contrast gutter next to the line number for errors and warnings?

Comment: If you write code you will see those underlined errors. If you want to fix all errors in file you can open problems view (ctrl + shift + m).

Comment: I see the underline, but I think its hard to see. Thats why I want gutters. Or at least highlight the entire text, not only underline it.

Comment: Well, for me it shows indicators in the scrollbar (right of the screen).

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time and managed to make errors in vs code more visible. Still not in the gutter, but better then nothing. I replaced vs code squiggly error and warning underlines with background and thick underline:

[image][image]

(offtop: also on screenshot you can see how "Bracket Pair Colorizer" extension works :)

Install [CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) and carefully follow all instructions (i had problem with link to css, which in windows must be like **file:///C:/myfolder/myfile.css** ... better read whole extension instructions)

Create a css file with contents:

```
.monaco-editor.vs .squiggly-warning,
.monaco-editor.vs-dark .squiggly-warning {
  /* background */
  background: #f2e3b3;
  /* underline */
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ffc000; 
}
.monaco-editor.vs .squiggly-error,
.monaco-editor.vs-dark .squiggly-error {
  /* background */
  background: #ffc7c7;
  /* underline */
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ff0000; 
}
```

And place link to it in **settings.json** like said in [CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) extension instructions

```
"vscode_custom_css.imports": ["file:///C:/yourfolder/youfilewithcustom.css"],
"vscode_custom_css.policy": true,
```

, then reload...

You can get color box around error (**instead** of underline, not simultaniously) if you use for example (**border:** instead of **border-bottom:** ):

```
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
```

Or you can get custom border from any side (right border alone seems to look great, tried this while writing this post)

[image]

```
.monaco-editor.vs .squiggly-warning,
.monaco-editor.vs-dark .squiggly-warning {
  background: #f2e3b3;
  border-right: 5px solid #ffc000;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ffc000;
  border-top: 3px solid #ffc000;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffc000;
}
.monaco-editor.vs .squiggly-error,
.monaco-editor.vs-dark .squiggly-error {
  background: #ffc7c7;
  border-right: 5px solid #ff0000;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ff0000;
  border-top: 3px solid #ff0000;
  border-left: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

This css will only replace squiggle color from green to yellow:

```
.monaco-editor.vs .squiggly-warning,
.monaco-editor.vs-dark .squiggly-warning {
/* yellow squiggly */
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='3' width='6'><g fill='#FF0'><path d='M5.5 0l-3 3H1.1l3-3z'/><path d='M4 0l2 2V.6L5.4 0zM0 2l1 1h1.4L0 .6z'/></g></svg>") repeat-x 0 100%;
}
```

As you can see the name of class changed from .greensquiggly to .squiggly-warning, that's why css from previous answer doesn't work. 
To find out new error css class i used **Help -> Toggle Developer Tools**, where after deleting bunch of blocks, i could find the error and warning classes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps. If you change all levels of errors in ESLint to warnings and then install extention [Custom CSS and JS](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css) you will be able to transform green underline to something else.

```
.monaco-editor.vs .greensquiggly,
.monaco-editor.vs-dark .greensquiggly {
  background: rgba(239, 83, 80, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid #1976d2;
}
```

It can appear (greensquiggly) in some other places, but for me this is working.

Answer (score 1):

based on @last-on-space here is a full override + a small enhancement to make sure the styles dont overlap each other on consecutive lines

```
.monaco-editor .squiggly-warning,
.monaco-editor .squiggly-error,
.monaco-editor .squiggly-info,
.monaco-editor .squiggly-hint {
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.monaco-editor .squiggly-warning  {
    background: #ffc00030;
    border-bottom-color: #ffc000;
}

.monaco-editor .squiggly-error {
    background: #ff000030;
    border-bottom-color: #ff0000;
}

.monaco-editor .squiggly-info {
    background: #0e7fff30;
    border-bottom-color: #0e7fff;
}

.monaco-editor .squiggly-hint {
    background: #a2eeef30;
    border-bottom-color: #a2eeef;
}
```

also dont forget to add

```
"editorError.foreground": "#00000000",
"editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
"editorInfo.foreground": "#00000000"
"editorHint.foreground": "#00000000"
```

under `workbench.colorCustomizations` to hide the original styles